# Is it possible to integate spring, Hibernate and Restful using Maven?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I need to build a Restful web-service using spring and hibernate? I want to use Spring 4.2.2 and Spring security 4.0.3 and hibernate 4.3.0 Is there anybody who have already used this integration. And I am looking for a appropriate POM.xml , I am comparatively new, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely possible, and has been done by thousands of people many times! Have you tried? Have you read the documentation of the libraries? What specific problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

Your pom.xml really depends on what you are doing, but this subsection of a typical pom should get you going (showing how to use properties).  You will need to add further dependencies as required (or remove those not required), and change the hiberate version:

```
    <properties>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <!-- NOTE Spring-security 4.0.3 is tied to core version 4.2.2; don't change one without the other!! -->
    <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

    <!-- persistence -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.13.Final</hibernate.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Security Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```